# Why jquery have problem with onbeforeprint event?

Tags: jquery

I have the following function.

```
$(function() {
    $(".sectionHeader:gt(0)").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".fieldset").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("img[alt='minimize']").click(function(e) {
        $(this).closest("table").next(".fieldset").slideUp("fast");
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
    $("img[alt='maximize']").click(function(e) {
        $(this).closest("table").next(".fieldset").slideDown("fast");
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
});

<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onbeforeprint = expandAll;

     function expandAll(){
       $(".fieldset:gt(0)").slideDown("fast");
      }
</script>
```

For this html

```
    <table class="sectionHeader" ><tr ><td>Heading 1</td></tr></table>
     <div style="display:none;" class="fieldset">Content 1</div>

 <table class="sectionHeader" ><tr ><td>Heading 2</td></tr></table>
     <div style="display:none;" class="fieldset">Content 2</div>
```

I have several div class="fieldset" over the page, but when I do print preview or print, I can see all divs sliding down before opening the print preview or printing but on the actual print preview or print out they are all collapse.

I would appreciate if anyone comes with a solution for this.

Anyone have any idea why is this or how to fix it?

Thanks.

PS:Using a  does not work either ( I assume because jquery using toggle) and its not the kind of question I am looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easier way to do this is in the CSS, you can have different styles for printing vs the screen like this:

```
@media print {
  .fieldset { display: block; }
}

@media screen {
  .fieldset { display: none; }
}
```

The `.fieldset` class will display when printing, but not by default in the browser.  Be sure to take out your in-line `diplay: none` styles on `.fieldset` divs in the page, as they'll override either of these in a CSS file.

Comment: Thanks nick, and the problem with the onbeforeprint event it was because the same, the inline style.
Once again, thanks. +1.

Comment: I resisted the urge to downvote, but this won't work in IE8, which doesn't support media queries, and some of us have to support such antiquated browsers. `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint` still have utility.

Comment: @DerrkHenderson you can do the same thing with the media tag in your <link> include with the media attribute there, having your print overloads in a separate file. It's the same approach just not quite as simple as with newer browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to strongly suggest to you not to use this technology for printing. You need to rely on a setup that works without javascript for printing.

Although the method you are going for can be marked as clever although using:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">  css to modify for print  </style>
```

Will ensure that you get your expanded panels for print even without javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I will do, I was just curious of why would it not work the jquery and why it was not working either with css. As Nick Craver says on his answer, its all because the inline style.

Comment: I can mention another important benefit that developers should keep in mind that if you have even remotely content that might be of use to disabled (vision disabled) people you need to keep in mind that most screen readers still don't work well with javascript or totally disable it. So all functionality on the client still needs to work fine if you have your js disabled.

Answer (score 1):

A JavaScript solution is available for the need is not using [onbeforeprint event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeprint) (which is not supported in some browsers), but use the [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia) API.

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("print");
mql.addListener(function(mql){
  if(mql.matches){
     // on before print
  }else{
     // on after print
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an jquery polyfill:

```
/**
* jQuery polyfill to handle beforeprint/afterprint on webkit-based browsers.
*/
(function ($) {
  // TODO: for some reason events are coming twice, need to debounce them
  if ((window.onbeforeprint === undefined || window.onafterprint === undefined)
    && window.matchMedia
  ) {
    var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
    mediaQueryList.addListener(function (mql) {
      if (mql.matches) {
        $(window).trigger('beforeprint');
      } else {
        $(window).trigger('afterprint');
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

With polyfill behind you will be able to handle onbeforeprint/onafterprint in obvious way for webkit-based browsers and IE, Firefox with jquery:

```
$(window).on('beforeprint', ...);
$(window).on('afterprint', ...);
```